# Accessing a UIButton in a custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift

I am very puzzled.

In my cellForRowAtIndexPath method, I am trying to set a UIButton title:

Not working:

```
  cell?.react?.setTitle("\(currentObject.likes)", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

where `react` is a UIButton, that is a subview of my UITableViewCell subclass.

I can't seem to update the title of my UIButton at all. The only way I have found to modify it is through the UITapGestureRecognizer in my UITableViewCell subclass,

Working:

```
func reaction(button : UIButton) {
    if button.imageView?.image == UIImage(named: "ic_favorite.png") {
        button.setImage(UIImage(named: "ic_favorite_border.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    } else {
    button.setImage(UIImage(named: "ic_favorite.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    }
}
```

Comment: is `react` is your button? Why you write `where react is a subclass of my custom cell.`?

Comment: where you declared the action of reaction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a custom cell (say myCell), add the button as an @IBOutlet, then type this `let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("yourIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! myCell`.

Your problem I think is that you haven't linked the button to the cell & XCode doesn't know which button you are talking about.

Comment: react is the button name!

Comment: Okay, this is not ideal but it worked. I just linked it through IB and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You should first get a reference to your cell with `cellForRowAtIndexPath` passed to your method.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MyCellIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UIButton        
    // do anything with cell
    return cell
}
```

Remember to set an identifier for your Table View Cell (`UITableViewCell`).

Comment: Regarding you editing of older posts: Please don't edit old posts just to remove things like "You're welcome. Please see: "[A moderator messaged me that my edits which only remove “thanks” and alike are discouraged](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/333096/3773011)".

Answer (score 0):

// try like this, first give tag for that button in your table cell

```
(cell?.contentView.viewWithTag(tag) as? UIButton)?.setTitle("\(currentObject.likes)", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```